# read.csv() R x must be numeric

Tags: r

I am trying to read data out of a csv-file.
The data consists of small integer numbers (53, 98 ...)

The csv was made with OpenOffice, the data stood there in the first column
one number in each row.

reading data was simple (no problem at all):

```
BirthNumbers <- read.csv(“/Users/.../RawData.csv”, header=FALSE)
```

Now I try to calculate `mean(BirthNumbers)` (for example),
but it is not possible, the error message:
x is not numeric

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for all help
Norbert

Comment: You might be better off on R-help or StackOverflow. Anyway, you think they are all numbers, R does not, so look for some other characters in the field.

Comment: Sorry but this stack is only for questions on statistics, programming is considered off topic. You can easily Google a solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably being read in as characters.
Try `mean(as.numeric(BirthNumbers))`

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html (see `Value` section), `read.csv` returns a data frame.

You should be calling `mean` on the column of the data frame. Since you have no headers (given your `header = FALSE`), most likely the column is called `V1` (verify by doing `head(BirthNumbers)` or `colnames(BirthNumbers)`), so you should do `mean(BirthNumbers$V1)`.